# How to retrieve Parameters passed through Jquery Mobile ChnagePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

On click of a Button , i am redirecting to a page known as qrcode.html as shown below

```
$(document).on('click', '.qrcode', function() {
     $.mobile.changePage("qrcode.html?UUID="+uuid+'&cust_id='+cust_id);
 });
```

This is redirecting to the qrcode.html page , where i am trying to fetch the parameters as shown

**Inside qrcode.html page**

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#homedeliverypage", function( event )
{
        var UUID = getParameterByName('UUID');
         var   cust_id = getParameterByName('cust_id');
         alert(UUID);
});
```

To my surprise the alert is not displayed even null also

Could you please let me know how to retrive the parameters ??

Answer (score 0):

I do this using JQuery with PHP...

Step 1 change page:

```
$.mobile.changePage('./myPage.php', { data: {theData: theData} });
```

Step 2 pick up the parameter using PHP:

```
<?php 
  $myData = $_GET['theData'];
?>
```

I normally do this to run PHP calls etc but you can simply add this variable as a hidden input type, which can then be grabbed in JQuery

```
<input type='hidden' name='myData' id='myData' value=<?php echo $myData ?> />
```

OR the JQuery only way.... (after step 1...)

```
<div id="testDataDiv"></div>

<script>
  $(document).one("pageinit", "#myPageName", function () {
    var myData = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];
    $('#testDataDiv').html(myData);
  });
</script>
```